# Command 'python' not found

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install python 3.8 on ubuntu 18.04.

```sh
python ––version
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8
python ––version and it gives me "sudo apt install python3
sudo apt install python
sudo apt install python-minimal. You also have python3 installed, you can run 'python3' instead.
```

How do I install?

Comment: Did you try `python3` ***like the message itself suggests***?

Comment: `You also have python3 installed, you can run 'python3' instead.`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing "python" in the terminal to start your environment, try with "python3". (Same goes for "pip" and "pip3"). Also, you could create an alias in your .bashrc file to access the Python3 command just by typing Python. If you would like, I can show you how to do it.

Go to your root directory in your terminal, and open the file called ".bashrc" with your favorite editor. To open in VSCode for example, just enter code .bashrc. At the end of the file, add a line that says alias python="python3". Assuming the python3 command worked, you will now be able to enter python just like you could python3!

Comment: Ok, so go to your root directory in your terminal, and open the file called ".bashrc" with your favorite editor. To open in VSCode for example, just enter ```code .bashrc```. At the end of the file, add a line that says ```alias python="python3"```. Assuming the ```pyhton3``` command worked, you will now be able to enter ```python``` just like you could ```python3```!

Comment: @JoshMerrian Welcome to SO. Your answer seems to be split between the answer text and a comment. Please move your comment to the answer text to make it complete.